# How to add clickTag for <noscript> alternate/fallback in HTML5 Ads?

Tags: javascript, html, noscript, clicktag

I realize there's not quite any "standards" in place for creating HTML5 ads.
But is there a best practice for entering a ***clickTag*** on Ads that makes use of `<noscript>`?

I assume this implementation largely depends on the ad-server it's uploaded to, but how could the ***clickTag*** dynamically change if Javascript is disabled?

Could it change on the server-side (ex: replaced upon request via PHP) even though the page has an `*.html` extension instead of `*.php`?

So far I have this for the HTML of an Ad:

```
<body>
    <!--Won't Work for noscript!-->
    <a href="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag+_local1);">
      <div id="content">
        <noscript>
          <img src="backup.jpg" alt="backup image">
        </noscript>
      </div>
    </a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _local1 = '80205';
        var clickTag = "http://www.google.com/";
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You'd need to do it server side. Whether or not you can run php in a .html would really depend on your HTTP server's configuration. It is possible, it's just a matter of configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Ad-server that supports `<noscript>` should change the value on the server side before serving the ad (see their specs). If not, I believe the only option would be to hard code the link.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/80205" onclick="window.open(window.clickTag+_local1); return false;">
    <div id="content">
        <noscript>
            <img src="backup.jpg" alt="backup image">
        </noscript>
    </div>
</a>
```

If you do it like above, the clickTag will be used if javascript is available and otherwise user will be sent to the hard coded url.